# catalog_product_view.xml is loading from vendor folder, instead of theme folder

Tags: magento2, sidebar, category-view, ultimo, sidemenu

I'm trying to remove the category title & category images from category view page. However, when i edit the **catalog_product_view.xml** from the (Infortis Ultimo) theme folder

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

it did not work, but when I edit the **catalog_product_view.xml** from the vendor folder

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

then it works.

I'm trying to get it done through the theme folder, how do i achieve it?

below is the code i need to add.

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are changing in wrong File.

The code you want to add is related with category image and sidebar.

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

**catalog_category_view.xml** is for category's product listing page whereas

**catalog_product_view.xml** is for Product detail page.

You are changing in different file in vendor folder to see changes but you edit "product_view" in your theme.

Comment: aha! thanks for noting that. So in the case that catallog_product_view.xml does not exist in the theme folder. I will just copy it from the vendor folder and edit from there? thanks!

Comment: yes. you should copy from vendor and put it in your theme path.